# Place a window in JFrame using Swing

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am creating a Desktop application that has to capture the face and show the emotions.The face will be captured first and a thread will be started to run a separate application(C++) to show the emotions.So each captured frame will be sent to C++ which shows the emotions in a separate window.I want to show this window inside a JFrame.Any method to do this in Swing?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I don't think this is possible.

Comment: Do you mean `JInternalFrame` / `JDesktop`? Like this: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/433c33/jinternalframe-with-jdesktop-pane-in-swing/

Comment: @Moritz, this looks good but the window will be created by C++ exe but the one given in the above link creates the window in Swing itself.

Comment: @santhosh Unfortunately I think this is not possible.

Comment: Why don't you just stick to one GUI implementation only? Read and send pictures from Java to the C++ app, receive an emotion-code from C++ and display the emotion image in Java. Don't you have the C++ code?

Comment: @Costis, This was the requirement given to me. Will there be no delay when we send,receive and display the image in frame? Please have a look at this link for what i am saying.  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mA883X4uaHk

Comment: Nice app! There will hardly be any delay. Could be done 100% Java. Would give you also the advantage of full portability to any OS, for what it's worth...